# How to get Windows identifiers in Unity?

Tags: unity, windows, management

I'm trying to get an unique computer (Windows) id in Unity. I can get it in *.net Framework* using this code, that I found somewhere:

```cs
class Security
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a 16 byte Unique Identification code of a computer
        /// Example: 4876-8DB5-EE85-69D3-FE52-8CF7-395D-2EA9
        /// </summary>
        private static string fingerPrint = string.Empty;
        public static string Value()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fingerPrint))
            {
                fingerPrint = GetHash("CPU >> " + cpuId() + "\nBIOS >> " +
            biosId() + "\nBASE >> " + baseId() +
            //"\nDISK >> "+ diskId() + "\nVIDEO >> " + 
            videoId() + "\nMAC >> "// + macId()
                                        );
            }
            return fingerPrint;
        }
        private static string GetHash(string s)
        {
            MD5 sec = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] bt = enc.GetBytes(s);
            return GetHexString(sec.ComputeHash(bt));
        }
        private static string GetHexString(byte[] bt)
        {
            string s = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < bt.Length; i++)
            {
                byte b = bt[i];
                int n, n1, n2;
                n = (int)b;
                n1 = n & 15;
                n2 = (n >> 4) & 15;
                if (n2 > 9)
                    s += ((char)(n2 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
                else
                    s += n2.ToString();
                if (n1 > 9)
                    s += ((char)(n1 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
                else
                    s += n1.ToString();
                if ((i + 1) != bt.Length && (i + 1) % 2 == 0) s += "-";
            }
            return s;
        }

        #region Original Device ID Getting Code
        //Return a hardware identifier
        private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty, string wmiMustBeTrue)
        {
            string result = "";
            System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
            System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                if (mo[wmiMustBeTrue].ToString() == "True")
                {
                    //Only get the first one
                    if (result == "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (NullReferenceException e)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        //Return a hardware identifier
        private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
        {
            string result = "";
            System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
            System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                //Only get the first one
                if (result == "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        private static string cpuId()
        {
            //Uses first CPU identifier available in order of preference
            //Don't get all identifiers, as it is very time consuming
            string retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "UniqueId");
            if (retVal == "") //If no UniqueID, use ProcessorID
            {
                retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId");
                if (retVal == "") //If no ProcessorId, use Name
                {
                    retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Name");
                    if (retVal == "") //If no Name, use Manufacturer
                    {
                        retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Manufacturer");
                    }
                    //Add clock speed for extra security
                    retVal += identifier("Win32_Processor", "MaxClockSpeed");
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        //BIOS Identifier
        private static string biosId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "IdentificationCode")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "ReleaseDate")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Version");
        }
        //Main physical hard drive ID
        private static string diskId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Model")
            + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Manufacturer")
            + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Signature")
            + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "TotalHeads");
        }
        //Motherboard ID
        private static string baseId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Model")
            + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer")
            + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Name")
            + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "SerialNumber");
        }
        //Primary video controller ID
        private static string videoId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_VideoController", "DriverVersion")
            + identifier("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
        }
        //First enabled network card ID
        private static string macId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration",
                "MACAddress", "IPEnabled");
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I know that I can't use *System.Management* in Unity, but I found the [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html) with `deviceUniqueIdentifier` that returns "unique" computer id. As described there -

> returns a hash from the concatenation of strings taken from Computer System Hardware Classes

So I understood that I can get access to *wmiProperties*, but I don't understand how. I know that there are already some "useful" properties in *SystemInfo* class, but I want to access them by myself. How can I get access to these instances from Unity, like I did in *.net Framework*?

As @DMGregory said, I should create class library respecting [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) manual. I have created a class library under *.NET Standart 2.1*, added reference to *System.Management* in this project and built it. Then moved out .dll file to Assets folder in my Unity project and there was no errors, until I ran my app. I got the error:

```
NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
System.Management.ManagementClass..ctor (System.String path) (at <3f5769dab130437396b36bc35518b77d>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Management.ManagementClass..ctor(string)
SecurityInsideLibrary.SecurityInside.identifier (System.String wmiClass, System.String wmiProperty) (at <ffa76661f32b42f8b5668f4fbd34bc67>:0)
SecurityInsideLibrary.SecurityInside.cpuId () (at <ffa76661f32b42f8b5668f4fbd34bc67>:0)
SecurityInsideLibrary.SecurityInside.Value () (at <ffa76661f32b42f8b5668f4fbd34bc67>:0)
SecurityHelper.GetValue () (at Assets/SecurityHelper.cs:10)
MainMenuScript.Awake () (at Assets/Scenes_Legacy/UI/MainMenuScript.cs:48)
```

The class library code (It is almost the same as I pasted before):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace SecurityInsideLibrary
{
    public class SecurityInside
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a 16 byte Unique Identification code of a computer
        /// Example: 4876-8DB5-EE85-69D3-FE52-8CF7-395D-2EA9
        /// </summary>
        private static string fingerPrint = string.Empty;
        public static string Value()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fingerPrint))
            {
                fingerPrint = GetHash("CPU >> " + cpuId() + "\nBIOS >> " +
            biosId() + "\nBASE >> " + baseId() +
            //"\nDISK >> "+ diskId() + "\nVIDEO >> " + 
            videoId() + "\nMAC >> "// + macId()
                                        );
            }
            return fingerPrint;
        }
        private static string GetHash(string s)
        {
            MD5 sec = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] bt = enc.GetBytes(s);
            return GetHexString(sec.ComputeHash(bt));
        }
        private static string GetHexString(byte[] bt)
        {
            string s = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < bt.Length; i++)
            {
                byte b = bt[i];
                int n, n1, n2;
                n = (int)b;
                n1 = n & 15;
                n2 = (n >> 4) & 15;
                if (n2 > 9)
                    s += ((char)(n2 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
                else
                    s += n2.ToString();
                if (n1 > 9)
                    s += ((char)(n1 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
                else
                    s += n1.ToString();
                if ((i + 1) != bt.Length && (i + 1) % 2 == 0) s += "-";
            }
            return s;
        }

        #region Original Device ID Getting Code
        //Return a hardware identifier
        private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty, string wmiMustBeTrue)
        {
            string result = "";
            System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
            System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                if (mo[wmiMustBeTrue].ToString() == "True")
                {
                    //Only get the first one
                    if (result == "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (NullReferenceException e)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        //Return a hardware identifier
        private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
        {
            string result = "";
            System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
            System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                //Only get the first one
                if (result == "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        private static string cpuId()
        {
            //Uses first CPU identifier available in order of preference
            //Don't get all identifiers, as it is very time consuming
            string retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "UniqueId");
            if (retVal == "") //If no UniqueID, use ProcessorID
            {
                retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId");
                if (retVal == "") //If no ProcessorId, use Name
                {
                    retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Name");
                    if (retVal == "") //If no Name, use Manufacturer
                    {
                        retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Manufacturer");
                    }
                    //Add clock speed for extra security
                    retVal += identifier("Win32_Processor", "MaxClockSpeed");
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        //BIOS Identifier
        private static string biosId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "IdentificationCode")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "ReleaseDate")
            + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Version");
        }
        //Main physical hard drive ID
        private static string diskId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Model")
            + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Manufacturer")
            + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Signature")
            + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "TotalHeads");
        }
        //Motherboard ID
        private static string baseId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Model")
            + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer")
            + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Name")
            + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "SerialNumber");
        }
        //Primary video controller ID
        private static string videoId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_VideoController", "DriverVersion")
            + identifier("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
        }
        //First enabled network card ID
        private static string macId()
        {
            return identifier("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration",
                "MACAddress", "IPEnabled");
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Solution explorer:
[image]

**Possible Solution:** I'm tired of waiting for someone who can help me, so I just changed my code like:

```cs
public static string GetDeviceUniqueIdentifier()
        {
            string ret = string.Empty;

            string concatStr = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcherBb = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
                foreach (var obj in searcherBb.Get())
                {
                    concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
                }

                ManagementObjectSearcher searcherBios = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
                foreach (var obj in searcherBios.Get())
                {
                    concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
                }

                ManagementObjectSearcher searcherOs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
                foreach (var obj in searcherOs.Get())
                {
                    concatStr += (string)obj.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value ?? string.Empty;
                }

                var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
                ret = string.Join("", sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(concatStr)).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

(I took the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809274/how-do-i-get-same-hardware-id-as-in-unityengine-systeminfo-deviceuniqueidentifie)). And the code returns the same string as *SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier* in Unity

Comment: In what way does `deviceUniqueIdentifier` differ from what you need, if your goal is just to have a unique identifier for the computer?

Comment: @DMGregory then I will have to change the algorithm (that I pasted) in another app, that  is already in using by users. And the unique Id from that app has to be the same as in Unity app

Comment: That should be part of your question then. Have you considered exporting your existing code as a DLL managed or native plugin, and invoking that plugin within your Unity code?

Comment: Could you please give me a couple of links to read about this or provide an example of how this can be done? I will be terribly grateful.

Comment: Start with [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) for an overview, then [type "unity managed plugin" into your favourite search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+managed+plugin&ia=web) to find relevant tutorials and Q&A.